# Err: documentTextDetection is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-vision

just follow https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext
got err when runs to the 3rd line

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const ocr = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const [r] = ocr.documentTextDetection(file.path);
const fullText = r.fullTextAnnotation;
```

> documentTextDetection is not a function

Ok to call `.textDetection()`

**`Environment details`**

```
OS: Win 10

Node.js version: 8.14.0

npm version: 6.4.1

@google-cloud/vision version: 1.2.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: documentTextDetection works for me node.js version 12.9.0   @google-cloud/vision version: 1.2.0 .  Can you post the full code you run?

Comment: @Brendan posted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, it works once doing it in a Promise

```
ocr.documentTextDetection(file.path)
      .then(
        function (data) {
          const [r] = data;
          const dr = r.fullTextAnnotation;
```